# how to fix multiple deployment of a web application in a server

Tags: spring-boot, threadpool, tomcat9

My web application (Spring boot 5+, hbernate 5.4,JPA ,Maven , JSP ) . on localhost machine(tomcat 9.0.17 & mysql v5.7.26) the website works fine, and can register new users form at the register.jsp page .

When I deploy the war file at the remote server (Tomcat 9) ..the website works fine exept that when i use the form to register a new user I get below exception (though other pages of the website keeps showing normally):

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web 
   application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. 
   The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as 
   well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the 
   illegal access.
////.....
   2019-06-20 12:43:47,237 [Catalina-utility-1] INFO  
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application 
   archive [/home/proz/tomcat/webapps/proz.net/ROOT.war]
  2019-06-20 12:43:59,099 [Catalina-utility-1] INFO  
  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[proz.net].[/]- 
  2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
  2019-06-20 12:44:02,052 [Catalina-utility-1] INFO  
  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[proz.net].[/]- 
  Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
   2019-06-20 12:44:07,558 [Catalina-utility-1] INFO  
    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deployment of web 
   application archive [/home/proz/tomcat/webapps/proz.net/ROOT.war] 
   has finished in [20,321] ms
  2019-06-20 12:44:22,702 [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-9549-exec-57] INFO  
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[proz.net].[/]- 
  Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

In the stacktrace I noticed 2 deployment of my application which obviously the reason why I'm getting illegal access .

```
1- From dispatcher servlet ..I believe this SpringBootServletInitializer 
2- From WebApplicationContext ...?
```

where does the 2nd web initializer came from ?!! and why this exception not coming on the localmachine ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the exception in my case was that I added some configs in the application.properties file that conflicted with the remote server installation of the Tomcat :

```
  # Load on startup priority of the dispatcher servlet. 
  spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup=-1 
  # Path of the dispatcher servlet.
  spring.mvc.servlet.path=/
  # Path pattern used for static resources.
  spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**
```

After I commented the 3 lines (2nd,4th & 6th) ...and redeployed the war file... problem solved .

I have no idea why with Tomcat on localhost things were going without any conflict.